# I want to convert std::string into a const wchar_t *

Tags: c++, stl, wchar-t, stdstring

Is there any method?
My computer is AMD64.

```
::std::string str;
BOOL loadU(const wchar_t* lpszPathName, int flag = 0);
```

When I used:

```
loadU(&str);
```

the VS2005 compiler says:

```
Error 7 error C2664:: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string *__w64 ' to 'const wchar_t *'
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you have a std::wstring object, you can call `c_str()` on it to get a `wchar_t*`:

```
std::wstring name( L"Steve Nash" );
const wchar_t* szName = name.c_str();
```

Since you are operating on a narrow string, however, you would first need to widen it.  There are various options here; one is to use Windows' built-in [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) routine.  That will give you an `LPWSTR`, which is equivalent to `wchar_t*`.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ: You mean `wstring var = L"text";`

Answer (score 113):

First convert it to std::wstring:

```
std::wstring widestr = std::wstring(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Then get the C string:

```
const wchar_t* widecstr = widestr.c_str();
```

This only works for ASCII strings, but it will not work if the underlying string is UTF-8 encoded. Using a conversion routine like MultiByteToWideChar() ensures that this scenario is handled properly.

Comment: This should work fine for ASCII strings, but it will not work if the underlying string is UTF-8 encoded.  Using a conversion routine like MultiByteToWideChar() ensures that this scenario is handled properly.

Comment: You should use MultiByteToWideChar with correct codepage. To be precise, two calls to it are needed: the first to get the required length of the target wchar_t string and the second to convert the char string to the wchar_t string.

Comment: It will only work if wchar_t is Unicode and char is Latin-1 or ASSCII. The first 256 character values of Unicode exactly match Latin-1; the first 128 characters of Latin-1 exactly match ASCII.

Comment: This was the quick fix I needed for my situation.  Thanks!

Comment: cannot convert ‘const char*’ to ‘wchar_t*’

Comment: this gives me an error: `cannot convert from 'const wchar_t *' to 'wchar_t *'` I had to use: `const wchar_t* widecstr = widestr.c_str();`

Comment: @MattDillard If this answer is wrong, you could post a correct one ...

Comment: @Bersan - I did, 14 years ago... :-)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the ATL text conversion macros to convert a narrow (char) string to a wide (wchar_t) one.  For example, to convert a std::string:

```
#include <atlconv.h>
...
std::string str = "Hello, world!";
CA2W pszWide(str.c_str());
loadU(pszWide);
```

You can also specify a code page, so if your std::string contains UTF-8 chars you can use:

```
CA2W pszWide(str.c_str(), CP_UTF8);
```

Very useful but Windows only.

Comment: You probably want CA2CW. You might also want to add a basic explanation for the macro naming convention (eg: Const Ascii -> Const Wchar).

Comment: There is no CA2CW conversion function.  There is a CA2CT version but this simply calls CA2W.  See <atlconv.h> for a full list.

Comment: Incredibly useful. In my case, only `#include <atlstr.h>` worked, while `#include <atlconv.h>` didn't. Dunno why.

Comment: I would also recommend `CA2WEX` instead, which bypasses potential stack overruns.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Linux/Unix have a look at mbstowcs() and wcstombs() defined in GNU C (from ISO C 90).

- mbs stand for "Multi Bytes String" and is basically the usual zero terminated C string.
- wcs stand for Wide Char String and is an array of wchar_t.

For more background details on wide chars have a look at glibc documentation [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_86.html).

Comment: I believe those are in C standard; either way, they're in Windows too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Need to pass a wchar_t string to a function and first be able to create the string from a literal string concantenated with an integer variable.

The original string looks like this, where 4 is the physical drive number, but I want that to be changeable to match whatever drive number I want to pass to the function

```
auto TargetDrive = L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive4";
```

The following works

```
int a = 4;


std::string stddrivestring = "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive" + to_string(a);

std::wstring widedrivestring = std::wstring(stddrivestring.begin(), stddrivestring.end());

const wchar_t* TargetDrive = widedrivestring.c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

If one can use `CString`, leveraging `CString::GetString()` would be convenient.

```
    #include <atlstr.h> // to use CString.
    std::string s = "std::string 한글";
    std::wstring ws = static_cast<CString>(s.c_str()).GetString();
```

E.g. using MFC in Windows,

```
    std::string s = "std::string 한글";

    std::wstring ws1 = std::wstring(s.cbegin(), s.cend()); // Uh-oh.
    ::AfxMessageBox(ws1.c_str()); // does NOT print correctly.

    std::wstring ws2 = static_cast<CString>(s.c_str()).GetString();
    ::AfxMessageBox(ws2.c_str()); // prints correctly.
    
    // some more examples.
    ::AfxMessageBox(static_cast<CString>(s.c_str()).GetString()); // prints correctly. 
    ::AfxMessageBox(static_cast<CString>(s.c_str())); // Also works without GetString().
    
    // this is fine.
    std::wstring ws3 = L"std::wstring 한글";
    ::AfxMessageBox(ws3.c_str()); // prints correctly.
```