# char* to const wchar_t * conversion

Tags: c++, pointers, char, wchar

I need to convert  character pointer to a w_char * in order to use ParseNetworkString(). I've tried finding solutions to this myself, and while I have found one solution, there is one issue which blocks me from using it:

b1naryatr0phy said in an other post:

```
std::wstring name( L"Steve Nash" );
const wchar_t* szName = name.c_str();
```

this almost works for me, except that I can't just pass the string explicity, as its value is not always going to be the same, meaning I can't just put it in quotes. If I replace the parameter with a function call, then the first line gives me an error (example: std::wstring name(LgetIpAddress()); I've tried std::wstring name(L" " + getIpAddress() + " "); , thinking that it just needs a quotation mark after the L, but that doesn't work either.. any suggestions?

Thanks! :)

Extra Kudos to whoever can answer this!

link to other post: [I want to convert std::string into a const wchar_t *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246806/i-want-to-convert-stdstring-into-a-const-wchar-t)

P.S. Sorry, just to clarify, getIpAddress returns a character pointer

Comment: if getIpAddress() returns a wstring or a wchar_t* then you just need to remove the L before getIpAddress()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the type of `getIpAddress()`?

Here's a snippet showing how to convert a `string` to a `wstring` (using standard C++11, no error checking):

```
wstring to_wstring(string const& str)
{
  size_t len = mbstowcs(nullptr, &str[0], 0);
  if (len == -1) // invalid source str, throw
  wstring wstr(len, 0);
  mbstowcs(&wstr[0], &str[0], wstr.size());
  return wstr;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, c++ standard doesn't grantee that std::string and std::wstring elements are arranged in continuous memory block. So, it is better to replace std::wstring with std::vector<wchar_t> and  &str[0] with str.c_str().

Comment: Does not work for me in Visual Studio 2015: see https://snag.gy/Hh2lJV.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You looked at only part of the other answer. It continues with explaining you need to do a [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert from an 8 bit string to a 16 bit one.

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that wchar_t uses UTF-16 on your platform (which I presume is Windows, from your mention of ParseNetworkString()). It also assumes that the char* uses UTF-8 instead of a legacy encoding, since you really shouldn't be using legacy encodings anyway, even on Windows.

```
#include <codecvt>

int main() {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>,wchar_t> convert;

    std::wstring name = convert.from_bytes("Steve Nash");
    const wchar_t* szName = name.c_str();
}
```

If you are using legacy encodings then you should fix that, either by moving over to wchar_t APIs entirely (assuming you don't care about portable code) or by using UTF-8 as your internal char* encoding. If you insist on using legacy encodings then you'll need to use one of the functions that handles converting them, such as `mbstowcs()` (which is locale sensitive, which brings in a whole host of new problems), or use `MultiByteToWideChar()` which has some similar problems but meshes better with Windows locales.