# Unexpected results with wchar_t and c_str string conversion

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, wstring, string-conversion

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246818/1704355) to a related question, I tried to write a method that converts a standard string to a wide string, which I can then convert into a wchar_t*.

Why aren't the two different ways of creating the wchar_t* equivalent? (I've shown the values that my debugger gives me).

```
TEST_METHOD(TestingAssertsWithGetWideString)
{
   std::wstring wString1 = GetWideString("me");
   const wchar_t* wchar1 = wString1.c_str(); // wchar1 = "me"
   const wchar_t* wchar2 = GetWideString("me").c_str(); // wchar2 = "ﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮ@" (Why?!)
}
```

where GetWideString is defined as follows:

```
inline const std::wstring GetWideString(const std::string &str)
{
   std::wstring wstr;
   wstr.assign(str.begin(), str.end());

   return wstr;
};
```

Note: the following doesn't work either.

```
const wchar_t* wchar2 = GetWChar("me");

const wchar_t *GetWChar(const std::string &str)
{
   std::wstring wstr;
   wstr.assign(str.begin(), str.end());

   return wstr.c_str();
};
```

Comment: `// Why doesn't this work?!` - You have a pointer to a temporary buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `GetWideString()`, you are creating a new `std::wstring`, which has a newly allocated memory buffer.  You are comparing pointers to different memory blocks (assuming `Assert::AreEqual()` is simply comparing the **pointers** themselves and not the **contents** of the memory blocks that are being pointed at).

**Update**: `const wchar_t* wchar2 = GetWideString("me").c_str();` does not work because `GetWideString()` returns a temporary `std::wstring` that goes out of scope and gets freed as soon as the statement is finished.  Thus you are obtaining a pointer to a temporary memory block, and then leaving that pointer dangling when that memory gets freed before you can use the pointer for anything.

Also, `const wchar_t* wchar2 = GetWChar("me");` should not compile. `GetWChar()` returns a `std::wstring`, which does not implement an implicit conversion to `wchar_t*`.  You have to use the `c_str()` method to get a `wchar_t*` from a `std::wstring`.

Comment: Good point, but I've edited my question to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't realize that the std::wstring returned was going out of scope. (PS I've fixed the part that you said shouldn't compile. That was a typo).

Comment: Am I do understand that `std::string` uses `char`? As an old-time programmer trying to learn the new way of doing things, I'm having enough trouble finding justification for learning `std:string`. Don't tell me it doesn't support wide characters out of the box.

Comment: @JonathanWood `std::string` uses `char`, yes. `std::wstring` uses `wchar_t` instead. And in C++11, there is also now `std::u16string` that uses `char16_t`, and `std::u32string` that uses `char32_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the two pointers aren't equal. A `wchar_t *` is not a `String`, so you get the [generic AreEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243427.aspx).

Comment: Good point, but I've edited my question to clarify what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`std::wstring` contains of wide characters of type `wchar_t`. `std::string` contains characters of type `char`. For special characters stored within `std::string` a multi-byte encoding is being used, i.e. some characters are represented by 2 characters within such a string. Converting between these thus can not be easy as calling a simple `assign`.

To convert between "wide" strings and multi-byte strings, you can use following helpers (Windows only):

```
// multi byte to wide char:
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& str)
{
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo(size_needed, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}

// wide char to multi byte:
std::string ws2s(const std::wstring& wstr)
{
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr.c_str(), int(wstr.length() + 1), 0, 0, 0, 0); 
    std::string strTo(size_needed, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wstr.c_str(), int(wstr.length() + 1), &strTo[0], size_needed, 0, 0); 
    return strTo;
}
```

Comment: Is it correct to assume that without any special characters, my simple assign will work as expected?