# wstring to const wchar* using c_str()

Tags: c++, constants, wstring, wchar

I'm trying to convert a wstring to const wchar*, but the null terminations aren't working as I expect:

[image: index 4]

[image: index 5]

[image: code]

Is there any way to convert wstring to const wchar* in the manner that I'm trying?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to convert std::string into a const wchar\_t \*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246806/i-want-to-convert-stdstring-into-a-const-wchar-t)

Comment: have you tried const_cast?

Comment: @Beed, `c_str()` returns `const wchar_t *`. It's stored into a `const wchar_t *`. Why would a `const_cast` help?

Comment: I don't see the problem here? The type of your pointer is `const wchar_t*`, the debugger advances by *2* bytes on pointer increment. Which means the `+5` case is past the null character

Comment: The stuff stored at `works + 5` is something you promised never to look at when you used the language. Same with `doesntWork + 5`. Don't be surprised when you implicitly say you won't look there and then look there and don't get what you expect.

Comment: What problems are you experiencing? Because the statements are OK. In which context `doesntWork` doesn't work?

Comment: I look into my crystal ball and I saw that you're using `std::cout` instead of `std::wcout` to print `doesntwork`.

Comment: @40two
That is the code that I'm currently using, but it isn't solving my problem.

Comment: @user2002287 what's your problem? The conversion looks OK.

Comment: @40two
I'm not using any form of cout, I'm passing the strings into client code. When I use the doesntWork it throws an exception, saying the string formatting is incorrect. work has a null terminator which inhabits +4 and +5, doesntWork's null terminator only inhabits +4 (i think?) 

I've been working on this ALL day. I believe it has something to do with "works" bring a wide string, and "doesntWork" not having a wide null terminator?

Comment: @user2002287, `works`'s null terminator is just `works[4]`. Each element is one `wchar_t`. The null is `sizeof(wchar_t)` zeroed bytes in that case.

Comment: @40two I'm passing both strings into the same function. works works. doesntWork throws a wrong string formatting exception

Comment: @user2002287 are you passing to a function that expects a BSTR ?

Comment: @chris then I have no idea how they are different.

Comment: @user2002287 bear in mind that the result of `c_str()` is only valid until the next time you call a non-const member function of the string, or the string is destroyed

Comment: @user2002287 Then your client code is engaging in undefined behavior ( something like 40two's `cout<<doesntWork` )

Answer (score 3):

Both `works[5]` and `doesntWork[5]` cause undefined behavior. The buffers are only valid up to `[4]`, and `[5]` is outside that.

```
const wchar_t *works = L"Test";

works[0] -> L'T'
works[1] -> L'e'
works[2] -> L's'
works[3] -> L't'
works[4] -> L'\0'
works[5] -> undefined behavior, the program is broken if it ever tries to access this
```