# Popen utf8 path

Tags: c++, gcc, utf-8

i have a problem when i want to open a **utf8** path with **_popen**

So here is my code:

```
char buf1520[1500];
string testme;
const char * sroot2 = getenv ("systemroot");
string md5cmd2 = sroot2;
md5cmd2 += "\\System32\\certutil -hashfile ";
md5cmd2 += "C:\\Users\\Vuzee\\Desktop\\testč\\test.jar";
cout << md5cmd2 << endl;
md5cmd2 += " MD5";
const char* md5cmdnovo2 = md5cmd2.c_str();
FILE *p1502 = _popen(md5cmdnovo2, "r");

for (size_t count; (count = fread(buf1520, 1, sizeof(buf1520), p1502));)
    testme += string(buf1520, buf1520 + count);
    _pclose(p1502);

cout << "HASH:" << testme << endl;
cin.ignore();
```

On this cout afther path, i get this output:`C:\Windows\System32\certutil -hashfile C:\Users\Vuzee\Desktop\testÄ\test.jar`

So i think problem is because string cannot save UTF8 chars, so how can i fix that and call it in popen?

and for last cout i get:

```
HASH:CertUtil: -hashfile command FAILED: 0x80070003 (WIN32: 3)
CertUtil: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: What makes you think UTF-8 should ever work in Windows APIs?

Comment: You need to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 LE before making file system calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your application may store the string as UTF-8, but the Windows operating system has two flavors of application interface — neither is UTF-8.

You can make your application work using the [`_wopen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa298534%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) function, which handles `wchar_t` (wide-characters).  As a start, you will have to convert the `string` value in `md5cmd2` to a wide-string (casting to `char*` will not work).

Further reading:

- [I want to convert std::string into a const wchar_t *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246806/i-want-to-convert-stdstring-into-a-const-wchar-t)
- [_popen, _wpopen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx)