# How to convert a std::string to L data type

Tags: c++

Hello I start studying c++ and I'm trying to learn what data type is something that starts with a L, like

```
auto something = L"Monday";
```

What data type is auto?
And how do I convert a `std::string` to this data type?

`std::string my_string = "Hello World";` to  `? something = L"Hello World"`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=msvc-160

Comment: Thx, so L"" is a  wchar_t*, is possible to convert a string to a wchar_t*?

Comment: It's a [wide string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). There's a few ways discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246806/i-want-to-convert-stdstring-into-a-const-wchar-t) to widen a `std::string` into a `std::wstring`.

Comment: `L""` is not a `wchar_t*`. It's a `const wchar_t[1]`, and decays to a `const wchar_t*` in most contexts. Sometimes, the difference is crucial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`auto` is not a data-type. It is a placeholder that gets [deduced depending on the initializer used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

In your case, the initializer is a [wide string-literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) of type `const wchar_t[size]`, which decays to `const wchar_t*` when used to initialize the variable.

A wide string can be stored in a `std::wstring`.

How to convert a `std::string` (a narrow string) to a wide string depends on the source's character encoding.

Anyway, there are many others who asked that too:

[C++ Convert string (or char*) to wstring (or wchar_t*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/)